# How to loop through a pandas array?

Tags: python, pandas

I read several questions about for loop of pandas Dataframe, but couldn't work it out for my case

```
px=pd.read_sql()

for i, row in px.iterrows():
    if x == 1 :
        if px['first'] <= S1 :
            S1 = px['first'];

        if px['second'] > S2 :
            previous_value = last_value;
            last_value = px['second'];
            x = 0;
    else :
.....
```

This is, of course, part of the code to show the looping logic. I expected that the rows are read one by one as I can compare the values of each row with the previous row, but

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the entire column `px['first']` from inside the loop that's intended to access only one entry at a time.

To fix your current loop, it *might* be enough just to change `px['first']` to `row['first']`, and also `px['second']` to `row['second']`.

Better would be to replace this manual looping with equivalent pandas expressions, which will be much faster and readable. If you post the full code (edit into question, not as comments!), we might be able to help.

Comment: I agree that pandars expressions will be much faster, but I doubt if it is possible to handle the whole code with pandas. I posted the original code from which I try to adopt the python code.

Comment: That's great to hear! Looking at the code you posted, I don't see a simple pandas way of doing it - and if the code runs fast enough as is, speed isn't a concern :)